# Set explicit modal width based on the content length

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I'm using a framework that requires explicit pixels for a modal window that will be used to display messages to the end user at various points in the system.  The messages will always be plain text so I want to base the width on the number of chars in the message. A message could be 2 words or 2 paragraphs.

At first I tried straight multiplication, which works great for `content.length` of 150-300 but anything <150 is too small and >300 gets way too large.

I need help with an algorithm that would effect a smaller number greater than it would effect a large number. I would like it to have the rough effect of:

```
getWidthForContent("small message") = 120; //13 chars
getWidthForContent("another reasonable length for a modal message") = 300; //45 chars
getWidthForContent("lorem ipsum...") = 900; //600+ chars
```

Another way you could look at this is trying to find a multiplier value from a curve. Here is a really sloppy approach:

```
determineBestWidth: function (contentLength) {
    var width = 900; //max
    if (contentLength < 200) {
        width = contentLength * 2;
        if (contentLength < 125) {
            width = contentLength * 3;
            if (contentLength < 50) {
                width = contentLength * 5;
                if (contentLength < 20) {
                    width = contentLength * 10;
                    if (contentLength < 10) {
                        width = contentLength * 20;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return width;
},
```

forgive me for my lack of math skills

Comment: So, you want to calculate the message width in px, am I right ?

Comment: close, I want to calculate an appropriate modal length in px based on number of characters in the message

Comment: Are you using `word-wrap`in this modal ? Like for example a max of 500px, then it breaks to another line and writes the rest.

Comment: Couldn't you just clip the width to a minimum of 150 and a maximum of 300?

Comment: except that if a message is an entire paragraph it should be closer to 800px

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a hidden div with the same content of your modal.
Then with some CSS tricks you will be able to do what you want (*if I understood what you wanted*) :

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

var modalHidden = document.getElementById("modalHidden");
modalHidden.innerHTML = modal.innerHTML;
var height = (modalHidden.clientHeight + 1) + "px";
var width = (modalHidden.clientWidth + 1) + "px";

var result = document.getElementById("result");
result.innerHTML = "Height : " + height + "<br/>Width : " + width;

if (parseInt(width.substring(0, width.length - 2)) < 500)
{
 modal.style.width = width;
}
```

```css
#modal {
    border: 1px solid darkblue;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #a4b8ff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    word-wrap :break-word;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#modalHidden
{
    visibility: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

#info {
    color: grey;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="info">Add some text and see that the width changes. Just use the variable in the JS and you're good.</div>
<div id="modal">
    Some short text
</div>

<div id="modalHidden"></div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

---

I made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnokcaLu/), if you wan to "play" with it.

Credits go to [Bacon Ipsum](http://baconipsum.com/).

Comment: tried running with the content "something small" and it looks like the modal width is still 500+ https://jsfiddle.net/k4cdpw0c/

Comment: @godmode Yep my bad, forgot this part. I updated both the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnokcaLu/) and the snippet. It should work now.

Comment: I appreciate your input, however this is not quite what I'm looking for. You essentially introduced the concept of a max-width. The reason I would like an algorithm is for sentences like `This is a really neat sentance. Hopefully the next one will land below.` It's not an overly long message so it doesn't really make sense to go all the way up to 500px when at 300px it would break once and look much nicer. Does that make sense? I'll still upvote your answer, I apologize for being difficult.

Comment: @godmode So you want to wrap after each end of a sentence ("`.`" character) ? Or do you want to wrap at `300px`, instead of `500px` ? I don't get what you really want :x But thanks for upvoting anyway !

Comment: @godmode The Excel I have here is giving me some shitty functions .. I'll come back to you as soon as I can, I need my computer for this

Comment: @godmode Nah I can't find a proper equation using Excel, sorry I can't help you any further :x